# WPF Datagrid with a Viewbox in a cell block right mouse button selection

Tags: wpf, datagrid, viewbox

I use a datagrid with templated cells to present my data. I can add any type of UI element I think of (DataTemplate, ContentControl, StackPanel, Rectangle) and everything still work fine. But as soon as I add a ViewBox, the right click mouse button (on the element) stop selecting the row/cell. Left click keep working properly.

As far as I know, a ViewBox is supposed to be visual only, but not to influence any event routing.

Sample code reproducing the problem (red rectangle works, green don't):

```
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}"
              IsReadOnly="True"
              AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"
                                    Margin="10">
                            <Rectangle Width="50"
                                       Height="50"
                                       Fill="Red" />
                            <Viewbox>
                                <Rectangle Width="50"
                                           Height="50"
                                           Fill="Green" />
                            </Viewbox>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I tried capturing the mouse event in the child control and send it to the parent but without success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution on this site (last comment by Yves.Z)

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/63fa1e10-1050-4448-a2bc-62dfe0836f25/selecting-datagrid-row-when-right-mouse-button-is-pressed?forum=wpf